# Scrapy: Scraping JS rendered page with Splash

Tags: scrapy

My goal is to scrape the following page: https://www.festicket.com/de/festivals/?country=DE

From what I read and learned so far, the best approach is either to find the API (which I wasn't able to) or use Splash as an extension. Is that the approach you would take, or did I miss anything?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to scrape.. But the page you are trying to scrape don't need API or Splash.. you can just use beautiful soup or Scrapy

Comment: Can I also "click the" "Load/See More" button at the end of the page without using Splash?

Comment: then  you need to use API 
`https://9f07q9i1om-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.29.0&x-algolia-application-id=9F07Q9I1OM&x-algolia-api-key=19e3128ee61a277541887302416c46a3`

`POST` request with some form data.. you can inspect on browser and see XHR network request

Comment: I tried to send this POST request via Postman but I only get the result `No content in POST request`. Not sure if I do something wrong here, or if it doesn't work that way.

Comment: you need to pass form data from the postman as well. Inspect the request on browser and see the network request headers for detail.

`
{"requests":[{"indexName":"prod_festivals","params":"query: 
hitsPerPage: 9
page: 1
numericFilters: ["end_date.timestamp >= 1578202324"]
facetFilters: ["country.slug:DE"]
attributesToHighlight: []
attributesToSnippet: []"},{"indexName":"prod_festivals","params":"query=
hitsPerPage: 1
page: 0
clickAnalytics: false"}]}
`